# How to Upload 4 images only using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

How to Upload 4 images only using PHP

this is my code .. this code is correct and i can upload 4 images

but when i upload 1 image .. i get error!

error like this: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\resize\uploader.php on line 10

Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\resize\uploader.php on line 24

Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\resize\uploader.php on line 25

Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\resize\uploader.php on line 26

Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\resize\uploader.php on line 27

Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\resize\uploader.php on line 28

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
//foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $loop => $name) {
for ( $loop = 0; $loop <= 1; $loop++ ) {
$files_folder = 'p/'; // files folder

$formats = array("jpg", "JPG", "png", "PNG", "jpeg", "JPEG"); // allowed formats

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["images"]["name"][$loop]); // temp name

$extension = end($temp); // ext

$file_size_megabyte = '5'; // set the max file size

$calculation = 1048576 * $file_size_megabyte; // convert from byte to megabyte

$max_file_size = $calculation; // result after converted

$rename = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 6)), 6, 6); // rename file

$uploaded = $files_folder.$rename.'.'.$extension; // uploaded file link

if ((($_FILES["images"]["type"][$loop] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$loop] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$loop] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$loop] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$loop] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$loop] <= $max_file_size)
&& in_array($extension, $formats)){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$loop], $uploaded);
echo $uploaded;
}


}

} 

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` and check are you actually getting data in a way you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

the HTML form is:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Pictures:
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>
```

The PHP code is:

```
<?php
foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: yes i know, but i want 1 input only .. i don't want 4 input!

Comment: you can use break in foreach when $key == 0